# Insert column based on logical conditions in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

I am selecting rows from my data based on either one of the conditions with the "filter" function:

```
Subset_data <- filter(Data, company_type == 3 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2,3) | company_type == 2 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2))
```

Now I want to add a column which has the value "0" when the row fulfills the first condition (company_type == 3 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2,3)), and the value "1" if the second condition is fulfilled (company_type == 2 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2)).

How can I do that efficiently (no looping if possible)?

Comment: Presumably you are using `filter` from `dplyr`. The `dplyr` way to add the new cols is `Subset_data <- Subset_data %>% mutate(first_cond = company_type == 3 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2,3), second_cond = company_type == 2 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2))`

Comment: I want to add only one column which has either 0 or 1 depending on the condition.

Comment: As mentioned what I want is having just **one** column added - your code adds two columns "first cond" and "second cond"

Comment: What do you want if neither met or if both met? (theoretically, I guess impossible for both company types to exist at the same time)

Comment: If neither conditions are met the row will no longer be in subset....as I am using filter. It won't happen that both conditions are met

Comment: See `?if_else` or `?case_when`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
Subset_data <- Data %>%
  filter(company_type == 3 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2,3) | 
           company_type == 2 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2)) %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(
    company_type == 3 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2,3) ~ 0L,
    company_type == 2 & annualturnover %in% c(1,2)   ~ 1L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_))

Subset_data
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  company_type annualturnover category
#         <int>          <int>    <int>
#1            3              3        0
#2            2              2        1
```

using this fake data

```
Data <- tribble(
  ~company_type, ~annualturnover,
  1L, 2L,
  3L, 3L,
  2L, 2L,
  2L, 3L)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `ifelse` then exclude `NA` cases.

```
dat$cat <- with(dat, ifelse(company_type == 3 & annualturnover %in% 1:3, 0,
                            ifelse(company_type == 2 & annualturnover %in% 1:2, 1, NA)))
dat <- dat[!is.na(dat$cat), ]
dat
#   company_type annualturnover cat
# 2            3              3   0
# 3            2              2   1
```

(Using *@JonSpring*'s data.)