# R formula to assign categories to data in a column based on 2 conditions in an index

Tags: r, if-statement, google-sheets, indexing, match

I have 2 sheets of data in Google Sheets. I would like to create a formula to sort the data in one sheet into two categories based on information in the second sheet.  I would like to find a solution, either using a formula directly in the sheet, after bringing it into R.

I've tried several ways to create a formula, but haven't succeeded.

I've also tried it a couple different ways in R, but haven't yet found a solution.

I am already able to get the data from the google sheet into R using the Google sheets 4 library.

Once in R, I have the data saved in two objects, "gs_dfId", and "gs_dfRunsheet".

One sheet, a sheet labeled "gs_dfId", contains an Id key with a number for each person.  The Id number is stored in a column labeled "Id".  The second sheet, "gs_dfRunsheet", contains the history of the transactions made by the people in the key.  There are 3 columns in "gs_dfRunsheet", the "Id" column, containing the same Id number corresponding to each person as the ID sheet, the "Retained" column, containing the amount retained, and the "Conveyed" column, containing the amount Conveyed.  If a person made a transaction that resulted in a zero in the column named "Retained", then I would like a new column added to gs_dfID with two colors, "white" for an Id with 0 (zero) retained, and "blue" for all other entries, including blank cells.  The new column of data can be added to the dataset in the "gs_dfId" object.

Here's the 2 datasets and a link to the google doc.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnl-yvI4itmYPvYoggL9pNVHw2r4ktgd_kqBbI0mHow/edit#gid=0

Runsheet:

```
Grantor Retained Conveyed
1       
2       
3      0       1
4       
5      0       1
6      1       1
7      0       0
7      0       0
6      0       1
10     0       0
8          0
9      0       0
11     ?       ?
7      ?       ?
7      0       0
11     0       0
8      0       1
10     0       0
13     0       0
13     0       1
13     0       1
15     0       1
10      
16     0       1
18     0       1
19  0.25 LRI   1
20  0.25 LRI    1
20  0.25 LRI?    1
20  0.015625 RI   0.015625 RI
```

ID:

```
Id  Color  
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9   
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15  
16  
17  
18  
19  
20  
21  
22  
23  
24  
25
```

If the Grantor in the Runsheet Retains Zero, then I want the Color column to have the word "white", and if it has any other entry than zero, including a blank cell, I would like it to have "blue"

I have tried three different solutions, but been unsuccessful at solving the equation.

First, I tried to write a google sheet formula directly in the google sheets, so that the colors would be assigned before the data was loaded into R.

```
=IF(AND(INDEX(Runsheet!B:B, MATCH(A2, Runsheet!A:A, 0)) = 0, A2 = INDEX(Runsheet!A:A, MATCH(A2, Runsheet!A:A, 0))), "white", "blue")
```

Second, I tried to use an loop with an ifelse setup.

found this question and answer, but have not yet figured out how to apply it:
[Insert column based on logical conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508089/insert-column-based-on-logical-conditions-in-r)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(gs_dfId)) {
  # Get the value in column A of the current row in the first sheet
  gs_dfId$Id <- gs_dfId[i, "A"]
  
  # Check if there is a corresponding row with a zero in the second sheet
  if (gs_dfId$Id %in% gs_dfRunsheet$Grantor && gs_dfRunsheet[gs_dfRunsheet$Grantor == gs_dfId$Id, "B"] == 0) {
    # If the condition is met, assign "white" to the current row in column B of the first sheet
    gs_dfId[i, "Color"] <- "white"
  } else {
    # Otherwise, assign "blue" to the current row in column B of the first sheet
    gs_dfId[i, "Color"] <- "blue"
  }
}
```

Thirdly, I tried to use tidyverse and set up a pipe.
I also found this quesiton and answer, but have not yet been able to understand how to apply it:
[Create a column based on a multiple conditions in data.table in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533070/create-a-column-based-on-a-multiple-conditions-in-data-table-in-r)

```
result <- gs_dfId %>%
  left_join(gs_dfRunsheet %>% filter(Retained == 0), by = c("Id" = "Grantor")) %>%
  mutate(Color = ifelse(!is.na(Retained.y), "white", "blue")) %>%
  select(-Retained.y)
```